# Changing the Developer Name in the Developer Member Center

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

Is there any way to change the "Name" field in the Developer Member Center?
When I created the developer account I thought that the "Developer Name" field is for my true name and not for the Team Name.
It's a little pain for me because this name appears under my app in the app store and I need my company name to be there...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Apple support [here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/).
Quoting from [Apple Support for Account Management](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/):

> **Updating Your Information**
>
> To update the Apple ID and/or email address associated with your
>   account, visit My Apple ID, click "Manage your account", and sign in
>   with your current Apple ID and password. **To update your address,
>   contact information, or *organization name*, please contact us**.